Cyclic Universe Problems
In Penroses's hypothesis, at the end of each iteration the universe undergoes a conformal transformation, meaning distances are rescaled. If I am right, it implies that a planet from the previous universe will appear as a microscopic object to us (planets from the previous iteration may still exist, as no big rip occurs).
So, won't that turn the planets, and even the galaxies into black holes, in later case with a large enough event horizon to be detected?

One detail maybe involved in getting the answer to this question straight is that CCC means "Conformal Cyclic Cosmology" (Penrose's cosmological model) in one  context, and (if I remember correctly) "Charged Coupling Constants" in another context, by (I think) Gupta, that also had a cosmological bearing.

If a Big Rip is not part of your plan to rid the expanding universe of mass, you are dependent on particle decay to get the job done right. This is problematic though because while photons are massless and a photon-only universe would theoretically be subject to conformal rescaling, an electron could not decay into photons because they would have to take its electric charge. This is a sticking point: all other particles could potentially dissipate yea it take $10^{2500}$ years - proton decay.
It is correct that massive particles and objects would not rescale along with the rest of the universe and their presence would prevent it happening because there cannot be any scale variation--there cannot be a loss of all sense of space and time rendering a potentially infinite universe into a potentially finite universe if there is any way to distinguish space and time at that juncture. Each massive particle has a different Compton wavelength which would be a stick in the nice even spokes required for the cyclic process. It is the said-to-be emergent masses in any new aeon which would bring about definition again.

thanks but as per Wikipedia, in his nobel lecture Penrose decided to allow some massive particles into the next aeon.

Yes, there is an awareness of that and that the massive particles would be electrons but there doesn't seem to be accompanying reasonable explanation yet for how they would lose their mass and charge thus existing in the required state for being part of a conformal transformation.

What's so special about the electron? Why can't it decay into a very low energy charged state? There is nothing sacrosanct about lepton number conservation. Even lepton number might be conserved if there are lower energy leptonic states.

@FlatterMann No, the photons need to be left alone. Electrons would interact.

@Wookie I don't know where you got the idea from that photons are fundamentally different from electrons. They are all just low energy states of the same quantum field. It's like saying p orbitals are fundamentally different from s orbitals.

@FlatterMann That's a firm position to take and I'll look deeper into it but currently I can only understand a conformal transformation with photons because they don't spin, don't have mass, don't have charge and will all be travelling at the same speed without interaction.

@Wookie None of the fields in the standard model have intrinsic mass. Mass is always effective mass. Charge and spin are just a quantum numbers. I also don't know what the speed of causality has to do with anything. We can always rescale physical units so that c=1.

If you are really standing behind these arguments then it would mean there are no requirements for conformal transformation and it is happening now. Please show that in your answer to the question.

@Wookie What makes you think that "it" is not happening now? If we are in a meta-stable state, then it is happening now. It is just happening very slowly. Nuclear decay rates and limits on the proton lifetime are giving you a hint for how slow it is happening. The universe is under no obligation to follow your preferred timelines. It has plenty of mechanism with which it can slow itself down.

@FlatterMann The same mechanisms seem to be slowing your answer down. This has nothing to do with my preferences for timelines, even though we are talking about a timeless state: I'm only answering that Penrose's conjecture doesn't pair with the Standard Model which is based on experimentation. If there is a massless charged particle, why haven't we detected it? Surely the probability of doing so is higher than the same for electrons.

@FlatterMann By the way, why do you separate us from the universe? That is what we are and always will be : )

@Wookie The "naked" electron in the standard model is massless. That's what I meant by "effective mass". Currently the effective mass is large, but if that coupling goes away after whatever causes the rescaling, then the mass scale changes. I don't know what you mean by "Why do you separate us from the universe.".
